# Class Inheritance, using Child Class to set up Parent Class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I am trying to learn a little more about Classes in Python, and am writing a program to help with this. I have defined my Parent Class and Child class as follows:

```
class Character():
'Common base class for all characters'
    def __init__(self):
        self.attack = 1
        self.defence = 1
        self.strength = 1

    def setAttack(self, attack):
        self.attack = attack

    def setDefence(self, defence):
        self.defence = defence

    def setStrength(self, strength):
        self.strength = strength

class Enemy(Character):
    'Enemy Class'
    def __init__(self):
        self.setAttack(random.randint(5,20))
        self.setDefence(random.randint(5,20))
        self.setStrength(random.randint(5,20))
```

This means I can define an enemy with the line

```
enemy1 = Enemy()
```

My view is I can then copy the Enemy class with different random values to create different types of enemy. i.e. Create a BiggerEnemy Class the same as above but with different random values.

While this code above works, all the text books and documentation I have read indicate I should structure my code as such:

```
class Character():
    'Common base class for all characters'
    def __init__(self, attack, defence, strength):
        self.attack = attack
        self.defence = defence
        self.strength = strength

    def setAttack(self, attack):
        self.attack = attack

    def setDefence(self, defence):
        self.defence = defence

    def setStrength(self, strength):
        self.strength = strength


class Enemy(Character):
    'Enemy Class'
    def __init__(self, attack,defence,strength):
        Character.__init__(self, attack, defence, strength)
        self.attack = attack
        self.defence = defence
        self.strength = strength
        self.setAttack(random.randint(5,20))
        self.setDefence(random.randint(5,20))
        self.setStrength(random.randint(5,20))
```

Which is fine, but this means I would have to declare what goes into the Child class by setting Attack, Defence and Strength in order to create the enemy

```
enemy1 = Enemy(10,10,10)
```

I am wondering if my method is incorrect, and if I am missing something about how classes work. All the documentation I have read seems to point to the fact I am wrong with my code, but the alternative seems to negate the need for the Child Class. Hence my first posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: So do you want random values for attack/defense/strength? Or the inputs?

Comment: I would like the random values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good practice to call the super-**init**-method, so I would suggest:

```
class Character():
    'Common base class for all characters'
    def __init__(self, attack, defence, strength):
        self.attack = attack
        self.defence = defence
        self.strength = strength


class Enemy(Character):
    'Enemy Class'
    def __init__(self):
        Character.__init__(self, attack=random.randint(5,20),
            defence=random.randint(5,20), strength=random.randint(5,20))
```

The setters are unnecessary.

Comment: Daniel, That looks really good! Thanks, I have been struggling to work out the correct way to implement this. Many thanks.